# Unable to start android emulator in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working on a Xamarin application (Android application). When i run my application on emulator, i get the following error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.EXE -no-boot-anim -avd my_device -prop monodroid.avdname=my_device
Emulator my_device cannot be started.PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT1>------ Build started: Project: ReadoutSoftware.XAndroid, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
```

I did set the environment variables like this:

```
ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\wnaveed\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT : C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
```

I have also tried this:

```
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT : C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
```

but i still get the same error.

I am new to Xamarin, so any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You should create a new emulator after setting the path of Android SDK .

Comment: Still the same error @LucasZhang-MSFT

Comment: Go to `My Computer'-> 'Properties' ->'Advance System Settings' -> 'Environment Variables' -> inside 'System Variables` add `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` or `ANDROID_HOME` and inside this set the path of your AVD. And don't forget to restart your PC, otherwise it will not work .